# Can I keep "unused css selector"?

Tags: svelte

I noticed that svelte will purge my css automatically, all "unused css selector" will get removed.

For example:

```
<p class="blue">This is a paragraph.</p>

<style>
    .red{
        color: red;
    }
    .blue{
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

The style for class 'red' will be removed. How can I keep the '.blue' selector? I want to use it later at some point.

Answer (score 13):

You probably want to wrap the selector in `:global(...)`, like

```css
:global(.red) {
    color: red;
}
```

This forces Svelte to keep the class around, and also makes it so the selector isn't scoped to that single component. This is usually what you want when Svelte is removing selectors that you want to keep.

Comment: While this seems to be the official recommendation, it's such a hack and will stump many users leading them down unnecessary debugging rabbit holes until they find this. Making you styling more verbose should be the very kind of anti-pattern Svelte would want to avoid.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use global in the style tag, if you have `svelte-preprocess` installed ([link](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess)):

```
<style global>
    .red{
        color: red;
    }
    .blue{
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can't find this in the docs and when used inside the REPL there's still the warning "Unused CSS selector ".red" (5:4)" https://svelte.dev/repl/05c5c9d5f7f549268bcde93377fd7902?version=3.46.3 Am I missing something?

Comment: @Corrl this is only when you have the package svelte-preprocess installed, apparently. I have updated the anwser

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution that doesn't use global styles. You can 'outsmart' the unused rule detector by using `:is()`.

```html
<style>
    :is(.red) {
        color: red;
    }
    .blue {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

compiles to

```css
.svelte-1xo9h64:is(.red) { color:red }
.blue.svelte-1xo9h64 { color:blue }
```

Please note that `:is()` is not supported in all browsers.
https://caniuse.com/css-matches-pseudo

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Sveltekit, you can create a app.css (or scss) file and import it into your main `+layout.svelte` file.

```js
import '../app.scss';
```

If you're not using sveltekit, you can edit the `global.css` file found in `public/global.css`

This [guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-beginners-guide-to-sveltekit/) explains the Sveltekit version in more detail

Answer (score 0):

I tried `:global()`, `<style global>` and `@import` but nothing worked. My case was something like this:

```
<ul>
    {#each items as item}
        <li class="method–{item.method}">{item.text}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

I finally found a solution that worked:

```
<li class="{'method-' + item.method}">
```

Makes no difference in the output but somehow doesn't trigger the CSS purging. Really annoying to have to deal with awkward tooling bugs.